# How to search for several strings in log file with bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have an issue optimising my bash script. I have few patterns i need to look for in the log file. If one of the patters is listed in the log file then do SOMETHING. So far i have this , but can and how can i optimize it without so many variables:

```
search_trace() {
    TYPE=$1
    for i in `find ${LOGTRC}/* -prune -type f -name "${USER}${TYPE}*" `
    do
            res1=0 
            res1=`grep -c "String1" $i`                
            res2=0 
            res2=`grep -c "String2" $i`                
            res3=0 
            res3=`grep -c "String3" $i`                
            res4=0 
            res4=`grep -c "String4" $i`
            if [ $res1 -gt 0 ] || [ $res2 -gt 0 ] || [ $res3 -gt 0 ] || [ $res4 -gt 0 ]; then
                    write_log W "Something is done ,because of connection reset in ${i}"
                    sleep 5
            fi
    done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) syntax in the regular expression you pass to `grep`, e.g.

```
if grep -q -E '(String1|String2|String3|String4) filename'; then
    # do something
fi
```

The `-E` option makes grep use [extended regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended) (including the alternation (`|`) operator).

Answer (score 0):

```
search_trace() {
    find "$LOGTRC"/* -prune -type f -name "$USER${1}*" |
    while IFS= read -r filename; do
        if grep -q -e String1 -e String2 -e String3 -e String4 "$filename"; then
            write_log W "Something is done ,because of connection reset in $filename"
            sleep 5
        fi
    done
}
```

grep's `-q` option is good for use in an if-condition: it is efficient since it will exit successfully when it finds the *first* match -- it doesn't have to read the rest of the file.